# Matrix dimensions in the spacetime interval equation don't seem to agree? (Possible notation misunderstanding)

Tags: special-relativity, covariance

The spacetime interval in flat space can be expressed as

$(\Delta s)^2 = g_{\alpha \beta} \Delta x^\alpha \Delta x^\beta$.

I understand covariant, $x_a$, and contravariant, $x^a$, vectors to be row and column vectors respectively, but, if this were the case, the matrix dimensions of the RHS in the equation above would not agree.

Have I misinterpreted this equation? Is my understanding of covariant and contravariant vectors incorrect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing wrong with the dimension. Once you put into the index and summation form, then it's basically adding up a bunch of numbers. Note that 
$$g_{\alpha \beta}\Delta x^{\beta}=\Delta x_{\alpha}$$
then your equation will be trivial.

Comment: At first glance, I was fine with this, as replacing $g_{\alpha \beta} \Delta x^\beta$ with $\Delta x_\alpha$ in the spacetime interval equation would solve my perceived problem. However, it just struck me that I have a problem with the equation in your answer, too. A matrix by a column vector would give another column vector, not a row vector: $g_{\alpha \beta} \Delta x^\beta = \Delta x^\alpha$. What gives?

Comment: normally we have $x^{\alpha}=(-x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3 )$ and $x_{\alpha}=(x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3 )$, while $g_{\alpha \beta}$ is simply a $4\times 4$ diagonal matrix with the diagonal elements being $(-1,1,1,1)$. The tensor $g_{\alpha \beta}$ basically serves to lower the index of the four vector. This is consistent with the Einstein summation rule. Therefore, the point is even though sometimes it helps to think of them as row or column vectors, it's quite naive and restrictive.